# A word for "Of or pertaining to lunchtime"?

Tags: word-request

As far as I understand, "*jentacular*" means "*of or pertaining to breakfast*" and "*crepuscular*" means "*active during the twilight hours*" which could be stretched to mean "*of or pertaining to supper*".

Is there a word that means "*of or pertaining to lunchtime*"? If not lunchtime, then noon, midday or something similar.

Thanks

Comment: You learn something new every day! But the full OED says that [***jentacular***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/111186#eid38710353) (from Latin *ientāculum*, breakfast) is ***obsolete***, so I don't think I'll bother committing that one to memory! Note that native speakers would *not* expect you to use ***crepuscular*** to mean "pertaining to supper" - imho it would be a bit weird even if the context made it obvious exactly what you meant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hee hee, perhaps I should have added a caveat that we love obscure and outdated words in our house, and use them a lot for the fun of it. Both of the words mentioned in my question are common around here, although we do get raised eyebrows when we use them outside :)

Comment: Crepuscular does mean "active during twilight hours" but "twilight" refers to both dawn and dusk. The stretch to use it to refer to supper may be fun, but is really far from English usage.

Comment: @Katy well cut of both my legs and call me Shorty, I didn't know that dawn could also be called twilight. Do you know of a word that specifically refers to dusk?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [postprandial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/postprandial), which refers to something happening after a meal, particularly lunch or dinner. I've heard it used to refer to after-dinner drinks, for instance. It's also common in discussions of blood sugar.

Simply prandial is also an option--it derives from the Latin for lunch, but in English means "relating to a meal."